# WordPress blog subdirectory with Laravel on nginx produces 404 error

Tags: wordpress, laravel, nginx

I installed a new WordPress blog thru Forge onto the same server as a Laravel 5.4 app. I put the blog in `blog.example.com` for simplicity sake, but I don't have any DNS actually pointing to the subdomain. Instead, I want to have `example.com/blog` pointing to my WordPress installation.

I then modified the nginx conf file for the Laravel site to look like this:

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/example.com/before/*;

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com;
    root /home/forge/example.com/current/public;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/230815/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/230815/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'SHA-HASH-HERE';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/example.com/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 600;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 600;
        fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }

    location /blog {
        root /home/forge/blog.example.com/public;

        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/blog.example.com-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/blog.example.com-error.log error;
    }
}

# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/example.com/after/*;
```

I restarted nginx expecting to see the WP installation when I visit `example.com/blog` but instead I only see a 404 error from the Laravel app.

What is wrong with my approach here?

Comment: give it try with `location = /blog` with match exact path.

Comment: What is that actual path to your blog index?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `index` file is actually `.../blog.example.com/public/index.*` then inside of your `location /blog` I believe you will want to change `root` to `alias`. Try that and see if it helps. The documents below go into more depth. If you do that, you may want to get rid of the `try_files` for that location. I would also browse the link at the bottom from NGINX, and check your config against those suggestions.

[NGINX Config](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/)

[NGINX Alias Docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias)

Comment: When I use `alias` I get the error `No input file specified`